# Non Convex Optimizations

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-optimization

I have a gd algorithm and I am trying to come up with a non-convex univariate optimization problem. I want to plot the function python and then show two runs of gd, one where it gets caught in a local minimum and one where it manages to make it to a global minimum. I am thinking of using different starting points to accomplish this.

That being said I am somewhat clueless about coming up with such a function or trying two different points, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really broad and really hard to answer because nonconvex optimization is rather complicated so is any iterative algorithm that solves such problems. As a quick hint, you can use the Mexican Hat function (or a simple polynomial that gives you what you want) for your test case. Also these papers can give you come context : [Paper1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.04915.pdf) [Paper2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.5549.pdf)

Good luck.